# IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'params.yaml'

Tags: ros-melodic, rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingServicesParams

```
$ rosparam dump params.yaml

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/bin/rosparam", line 35, in <module>
    rosparam.yamlmain()
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosparam/__init__.py", line 620, in yamlmain
    _rosparam_cmd_get_dump(command, argv)
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosparam/__init__.py", line 444, in _rosparam_cmd_get_dump
    dump_params(arg, script_resolve_name(NAME, ns), verbose=options.verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosparam/__init__.py", line 299, in dump_params
    f = open(filename, 'w')
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'params.yaml'
```

Where is params.yaml? Need I create it before this command?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348492/ioerror:-%5Berrno-13%5D-permission-denied:-%27params.yaml%27/) by [Dean](https://answers.ros.org/users/53030/dean/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2020-04-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Replace  with the name of your ROS distribution (e.g. indigo, jade, kinetic, lunar...):

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-<distro>-rqt ros-<distro>-rqt-common-plugins ros-<distro>-turtlesim
```

NOTE: you may have already built rqt and turtlesim for one of the previous tutorials. If you are not sure, installing them again will not hurt anything.

---

Originally posted by [Dean](https://answers.ros.org/users/53030/dean/) with karma: 17 on 2020-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-06**:
Is this an answer? Or an update?

It's unclear to me how installing `rqt` solves a permission problem.